# how to add active class for custom taxonomy to li

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created one custom post type and also created to custom taxonomy and display in front-end but the problem is not set, active class.

```
foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
                            $term = term_exists($cat->name, 'category_name');
                            if ($term !== 0 && $term !== null) {
                                echo $cat->name. 'category exists!';
                            }
                            if ($cat->category_parent == 0) {
                                $category_id = $cat->term_id;
                                ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_category_link($cat->term_id)); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
                                <?php
                            }
                        }
```

Please see this screen-shot: https://prnt.sc/gsm5yf

I want to set active class for 2 this category
can anyone plz help me.

Comment: add condition using $cat->name on li tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to do this easier and more WordPress-ish by using a [wp_list_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) with a custom category walker (if you have special requirements regarding output).

That being said, you should be able to use get_queried_object() to get the currently active term if you're on a taxonomy page. Once you have that, you can compare the element you're currently working on. e.g.

`$current_term = is_tax ? get_queried_object() : null;`

and in your loop, add

`$classactive = "";
if($current_term != null && $current_term->term_taxonomy_id == $cat->term_taxonomy_id) {
   $classactive = "active";
}`

Then you should be able to change your li-output to

`<li class="$classactive"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_category_link($cat->term_id)); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>`

and it'll be

`<li class=""><a....>First Category</a></li>
<li class="active"><a....>Second Category</a></li>
<li class=""><a....>Third Category</a></li>`